# rewrite column output to an existing file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have one line input like this.

```
TEST2="A=18&A=0&ANY=43&D=12&D=3"
```

Which I have managed to separate by column below using awk:

```
echo "$TEST2" | awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}'
```

---

```
A 18    
A 0   
ANY 43      
D 12    
D 3
```

But now how can i redirect this output to an existing file which already have 3 column in it:

```
A 15 text   
A 1 example   
ANY 21 text   
D 4 EX   
D 23 test
```

The final result should be (only column 1 and 3 unchanged):

```
A 18 text    
A 0 example  
ANY 43 text      
D 12 EX   
D 3 test
```

Solution:

```
echo "$TEST2"| awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}' | awk '{str1=$1; str2=$2; getline < "file"; print str1" \t "str2" \t "$3 > "newfile"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never found a need for this rather obscure and specialized GNU utility, but it seems to fit your requirement perfectly:

```
join -o '2.1 2.2 1.3' <(sort <file) <(echo "$TEST2"| awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}'| sort);
```

The join utility joins two files on a common field, defaulting to the first field of each file if you don't override it with the -1, -2, or -j options. The field delimiter defaults to whitespace, but can be specified (as a single character only) with the -t option.

The sorts are not technically necessary for your example data because it's already sorted, but since join always requires sorted join fields, it's a good idea to have them there. If joining on non-first fields, you'd have to use the -k option of the sort utility to sort by the appropriate field.

The argument to the -o option specifies the output format. Here's a quote from the man page:

> FORMAT is one or more comma or blank separated specifications, each being 'FILENUM.FIELD' or '0'. Default FORMAT outputs the join field, the remaining fields from FILE1, the remaining fields from FILE2, all separated by CHAR. If FORMAT is the keyword 'auto', then the first line of each file determines the number of fields output for each line.

So for example, 2.1 means the first field of the second file.

The command as I wrote it above won't overwrite the file, it just generates the required output. To overwrite the file you could add a redirection:

```
join -o '2.1 2.2 1.3' <(sort <file) <(echo "$TEST2"| awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}'| sort) >|file;
```

However, usually if you try to overwrite a file with a redirection in the same command that tries to use the (original contents of the) file as input, then it won't work, because the file might be truncated as a result of the redirection prior to it being read as input, so no input would end up being read. Now, testing on my current system, I'm actually finding that the above redirection works perfectly, and to be honest I'm not exactly sure why; I suspect the shell is completing the process substitution in which the file is read before it handles the redirection, but I'm not sure. I wouldn't rely on that to work in all cases or on all systems. So what you can do is redirect to a new file, then move it over the original file if it succeeds:

```
join -o '2.1 2.2 1.3' <(sort <file) <(echo "$TEST2" | awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}'| sort) >|file.tmp && mv file.tmp file;
```

Edit: I see you've edited your question to specify that there could be duplicates in the first field. I thought for a moment that that would nix my whole solution, since the join utility only does a DB-style cartesian product of the two input files, but then I realized we can synthesize a new join field with unique values.

I'm not sure if the `nl` utility exists on all Unix-like systems, but if you have it, here's how you can make this work:

```
join -o '1.2 2.3 1.4' <(nl -w1 <file) <(echo "$TEST2"| awk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=&]"}{for(i=1; i<= NF; ++i){print $i, $((i+1));++i}}'| nl -w1) >|file.tmp && mv file.tmp file;
```

The `nl` utility numbers lines according to the format you specify. I've just specified `-w1`, meaning a field width of 1 character, which just removes unnecessary padding whitespace which is normally added by the default of `-w6`. (Actually `-w1` is not even necessary here; join would ignore all extraneous whitespace.) The result is that every line of the input gets prefixed with its line number followed by a tab character as a separator, which join recognizes as whitespace when parsing into fields. Thus, each file ends up with an extra field; the line number field, and then the 2 or 3 fields of data. Hence I had to increment the field selectors in the argument to the `-o` option to join.

Another solution for prefixing input lines with line numbers is `cat -n`.

Comment: So if i want to change column 1 only it should be '2.1 1.2 1.3' correct? I have tried your code but it doesnt rewrite my file?

Comment: I am still trying to use your method to solve the duplicate issue but failed. I have found other method that work thou. i have edited my question with solution in case other people looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "$( echo "$TEST2" | sed 's/\&/#/g;s/^/#/;s/#\(.\)=\([^#]*\)/s_^\1 [^ ]* _\1 \2 _;/g')" YourFile
```

using a pre-substitution that generate a sed action list like: `s_^A [^ ]* _A 18 _;s_^B [^ ]* _B 0 _;s_^C [^ ]* _C 43 _;s_^D [^ ]* _D 12 _;s_^E [^ ]* _E 3 _;` from TEST2 content

Answer (score 0):

All in awk

```
awk -vS="$TEST2" '!x{x=split(S,a,/[&=]/);for(i=2;i<=x;i+=2)b[a[i-1]]=a[i-1]" "a[i]}
                  ($1 in b)&&$0=b[$1]" "$3' file
```

#### output

```
A 18 text
B 0 example
C 43 text
D 12 EX
E 3 test
```

Comment: what if the column 1 input have duplicate (say have two A or D)this would make the column 2 output in a mess right?